# Save image to canvas from video JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, html5-canvas

I get an error when I try to capture a frame from a video I just created.
It's after drawImage:

> Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or OffscreenCanvas)'

Any idea what might be the reason? Thanks

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```js
var $theImg = $('<video id="video" preload="metadata" src="http://localhost/screens/page/VIDEO/vids/' + file.name + '"></video>');
$theImg.attr('data-disp', name);
$theImg.attr('data-name', file.name);
$theImg.attr('data-created', 1);
$theImg.appendTo('#selectable-videos');
$theImg.addClass('selectable-image');
$(e.target).parent().parent().find('.modal-body').children().append($theImg);

var $canvas = $('<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>');
$theImg.append($canvas);

var canvas = $('#canvas');
var video = $('#video');

if (video.length) {
  var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  //convert to desired file format
  var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg'); // can also use 'image/png'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're proving a jQuery object to `drawImage()`, not a native Element object. You can use `[0]` or `get(0)` to retrieve the first underlying Element from the jQuery object:

```
var ctx = canvas[0].getContext('2d').drawImage(video[0], 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

Also note that you will have a similar issue on the following line when you call `toDataURL()` on the canvas.

```
var dataURI = canvas[0].toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

Note that the logic can be tidied as the use of similar variable names holding different object types is a little confusing. Try this:

```js
var $video = $('<video></video>', {
  id: 'video',
  preload: 'metadata',
  src: 'http://localhost/screens/page/VIDEO/vids/' + file.name,
  data - disp: name,
  data - name: file.name,
  data - created: 1,
  class: 'selectable-image'
}).appendTo('#selectable-videos');

// is this line really needed? You just appended it above. 
// also, use closest() instead of parent().parent().parent()...
$(e.target).parent().parent().find('.modal-body').children().append($video);

var $canvas = $('<canvas></canvas>', {
  id: 'canvas',
  width: 640,
  height: 480
}).appendTo($video);

var canvas = $canvas[0];
var video = $video[0];

// removed 'if' check - you just created the element, it will exist
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
var dataURI = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

Finally, it's very odd that you're appending a `canvas` to a `video` element though. I would suggest not doing that.

Comment: I changed 'video[0]' to $theImg[0] and it worked! Thanks bro